# How Hide url from communication between servers

Tags: php, security, server

Let's suppose I've a critical php script which runs on a server.
I want to access that php script from another server. I want to not only hide the communication data between the 2 servers but also the URL in order that each time i call the url it's never the same.
What is the best way to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: If the URL/IP address is hidden, how the DNS, router and the rest could handle the request? The question is: from who are you willing to hide the URL?

Comment: From potentials people in the middle.

Comment: I think (but I may be wrong) the URL or IP address is the only or almost the only thing that can't be hidden. Otherwise, how would it be possible to send the request?

Comment: Proxy the request from the first server to the second server, proxy it again on the second server and have the actual url only accessible to localhost if you like. Rewrite all the headers which are returned to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for Hiding Url, url is made up from multiple segments. and we can hide each segment as follow:

lets see the URL itself:

```
Scheme:://foo@host:port/pathes/querystringKey=val#fragment
```

so for each section you can hide hide it using an Encoding Mechanism,

> By The Encoding i mean, change to something that Eve Couldnot understand
> what is going on.

### The Scheme

can be Encoded When you using a **Tunnel** . **Tunnel** is another Protocol for Application Layer Communication which you can send your **Actual** Link in Tunnels **Payload**.
for Example :

- using `ssh` for transferring file is uncommon. but you can using that with `scp`
- using a Proxy which Encrypt **HTTP Headers** like **SOCKS 5**
- using a **VPN** since its Tunnels every packet.

### The User

Php scripts are not tend to Authenticate The User with **URL User Parameter** .

so it will be emitted.

### The Host

The Host can be ip and domain. since it will be used by network to route your traffic.

in order to make it hide (deform) you can use a proxy to do that.

if you are worry about intruders finding out the actual **Destination Host** you can use **Onion Routing** or **Garlic Routing**

### The Port

its simple as not using Common Ports on Client and Server . like not using 443 for https.

### Path

you can use one path like `index.php` and pass the **routing parameters** in Http Header.
Since Your Payload in Header Encrypted using SSL. you are not worry for that.

but if you are worry about to not have a **distinc** path. you can make a **random** path to mislead intruders and just eliminate the random path in Servers **Url Rewrire**. since you get the actual in Http Header and can Route The Request.

### QueryString

Query String can get into Http Header. b not Using Http Get Requests.

### Fragment

in PHP Url Interpretation, Fragment Plays no Rule